# Error: Failure while executing python Package Index

Tags: python, package

when I try to download Package Index newspaper from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/newspaper):

Then I follow instruction on the above link to install it on my Mac:

```
If you are on OSX, install using the following, you may use both homebrew or macports:
$ brew install libxml2 libxslt

$ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2

$ pip install newspaper

$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codelucas/newspaper/master/download_corpora.py | python
```

when I run

```
$ brew install libxml2 libxslt
```

the output :

```
Error: Failure while executing:  -L /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: libxml2 cannot be built with any available compilers.
To install this formula, you may need to:
  brew install gcc
```

and when I run :

```
brew install gcc
```

the output :

```
Error: Failure while executing:  -L /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: gmp cannot be built with any available compilers.
To install this formula, you may need to:
  brew install gcc
```

Comment: And have you run `brew install gcc` like it said to?

Comment: yes ..the result : Error: Failure while executing:  -L /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: gmp cannot be built with any available compilers.
To install this formula, you may need to:
  brew install gcc

Comment: so it told you to install it when you tried to install it. Can you [edit] in that error as well please.

Comment: are you sure you did `brew install gcc` not `brew install gmp`?